# Linking Firebase Authenticated user with 'users' collection in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

New to flutter, and first post here!

I am building a mobile app with flutter, using Firebase and Cloud Firestore. Each user, when authenticated (by email and password), is also currently then added to a 'users' collection in Firestore - like this:

sign up method:

```
    Future signUp() async {
if (passwordConfirmed()) {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: _emailController.text.trim(),
    password: _passwordController.text.trim(),
  );

  // add user details
  addUserDetails(
    _firstNameController.text.trim(),
    _lastNameController.text.trim(),
    _emailController.text.trim(),
    _baseStationController.text.trim(),
  );
}
}

Future addUserDetails(String firstName, String lastName, String email,
  String baseStation) async {
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').add({
  'first name': firstName,
  'last name': lastName,
  'email': email,
  'base station': baseStation,
});
```

}

The signup() method is called when they input their information into text fields within a form, and click a button. This works successfully, and my user collection receives the data, and sign in/out works as it should.

Those users have a 'base station' (which is stored as a field within that users document in Firestore) which is their place of work. I want to show a welcome screen when they log in, so that the current users 'base station' is displayed.

I can access their email address using:

```
final thisUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
```

and then for example to show this when they log in:

```
Text('Hello, ${thisUser.email!}')
```

this works no problem, however...

I can't work out how their authentication then links to the collection, so I want to show the 'base station' for the 'currentUser' for example when they log in (I don't want them to have to select their base station every time from a picker when they've already provided the information on sign up.

As an aside - I can also (separately) successfully read the data from the collection and (for example) create a listView builder with the users collection information, but this is for all users, and not specifically the 'currentUser' that is logged in.

All help gratefully received, apologies if I have missed anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update addUserDetails as follows    
 
 Future addUserDetails(String firstName, String lastName, String email,
              String baseStation) async {
            await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).set({
              'first name': firstName,
              'last name': lastName,
              'email': email,
              'base station': baseStation,
            });
```

if you then want to get specific user detail then use the code as follows

```
  final user = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).get();
```

Comment: when creating the user in signup only call addUserDetails only when the createUserWithEmailAndPassword function has finished executing, that is under it

Comment: Thanks a lot!, How do I then access that 'user' variable to show the information?

Comment: final user = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).get();

Comment: the above code will help you or you i made the snippet at the bottom of the first answer check it

Comment: Thanks - my apologies I didn't word my answer very well - I want to show the data on the screen for example the page just shows a text widget that says 'Welcome ${User.name}' ... but unsure how to do this.

Comment: it depends on what state management your using currently or are you using plane old stateful widget and setState?

Comment: yes - stateful widget and setState at the moment

Comment: well the easiest way to do that is create a state variable for the user at the top of your stateful wedget where you want to display the username, then create an async function and make your request to your db and when you get the user from your db set the user in the state equals to the user in the async function and then call the async function inside initState then you can say Text('welcome ${user.name}'); in your build

Comment: note that you cannot directly call async function in an initStat thats is why you need to create a separate async function then call the function in your initState